# [ros 2] How to create a non-node logger?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [documentation](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Concepts/Logging/) it says:

> Non-node loggers can also be created that use a specific name.

Is there an example or tutorial somewhere that shows how to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361542/%5Bros-2%5D-how-to-create-a-non-node-logger?/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2020-09-14

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, Jeff. I actually stumbled across the answer to this not too long ago. When you use logging macros in ROS2, the first argument is an `rclcpp::Logger` which you would normally get from calling `get_logger()` on an `rclcpp::Node`. However, the `rclcpp` namespace [also provides a `get_logger()` function](https://docs.ros2.org/dashing/api/rclcpp/namespacerclcpp.html#ae7295751947c08312aa69f45fd673171) which can be used to generate an `rclcpp::Logger` without a node instance by just giving it a name. I believe the only difference between this type of `rclcpp::Logger` instance and the one you would get from a node is the logger maintaining a reference to the node and changing its name if the node name changes.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2020-09-16**:
Perfect, thanks!

**Comment by [dannee](https://answers.ros.org/users/98755/dannee/) on 2022-09-19**:
If anyone is looking for the python answer, it can be called with: `rclpy.logging.get_logger(name)`